# Overflow:hidden doesn't seem to work together with W3.CSS

Tags: css

- If I apply the css attribute `overflow:hidden` to the body, it will
  works as expected. See [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/w4LViM0ZzV).
- But if I include CSS3 and add `body {overflow:hidden;}`, it will
  not work and I will be still able to scroll. See [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/gVLJncuM6j).

Why is CSS3 overwriting the `overflow:hidden` attribute? And how can I use CSS3 and `overflow:hidden` together?

Comment: Since there's no way to 'add CSS3' as a whole to your code, and it would depend on the individual properties you used, please include further details or a snippet in your question, or information about which browser the problem occurs in if that's the issue. In general, `overflow: hidden` works as it always did alongside CSS3 properties.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? CSS3 isn't something you have to include seperately. You're just including the CSS of w3schools.

Comment: @TheThirdMan it occurs on Firefox 45 and Chrome 50.

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my question

Comment: @d4rty You could put your CSS rule after the other CSS, or you could use `!important`. But, really, you should rethink your approach. There is no need to include all of the w3schools css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add CSS3, CSS3 is just an addition to CSS2, where browsers support more stuff than they did in previous versions.

For example:

```
div {border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

Now you have used the CSS3 definition for border-radius, meaning you rounded the corners of your element.

If you just paste a CSS from another source, it will break something on your site, only do this if you really know what ALL the CSS rules are going to do and if you really need it (in 99.9% you won't)